# Django React Nginx serving admin static files

Tags: python, css, django, nginx

I feel a bit awkward asking a question which has been answered before - however I feel there is a point of difference with regard to having node serve out the static files as opposed to django. The css bundled by webpack and served by node is working with no problems, where I'm having issues is serving up the admin css and another couple of other files using the get_static_prefix decorator.

The file structure is as follows:

```
root
    |
     public
        - templates
        - static
             | <-- collectstatic adding files here
        - vendor
    |
      server
        - app1
        - app2
             | settings.py
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/project

```
 server {
     listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000;
     server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
     location /static {
            alias /root/se/env/public/static/;
    }
}
```

and the setup in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/root/se/env/public/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ONLY_URL = '/static_only/'

if not DEBUG:
    MEDIA = '/media',
    STATIC_ROOT = '/root/se/env/public/static/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'public', 'media')
    STATICFILES_DIRS = '/root/se/env/public/vendor/static/',
```

I've been going around in circles for a while now. I'm pretty new to Django and don't really get how this works. From what I can understand the the STATICFILES_DIRS are where collectstatic gathers the static files from and the STATIC_ROOT is where the static files are dumped after collectstatic is run. I think the STATIC_URL is where I'm going wrong - but I'm not having much luck figuring it out.

As it stands the admin css isn't working when DEBUG = True now either, so I've misconfigured something. It's resulting in:

```
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
```

Comment: Did you try changing STATIC_URL to "/static/"? Also try changing the nginx location /static to /static/.

Comment: @Kamal -  thanks for your reply. I've tried that but still getting nothing. I've updated the question with a bit more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `location /static` is wrong. The `alias` directive substitutes parts of the URI when forming the pathname. The `location` parameter and the `alias` parameter should both end with a `/`, or neither end with a `/`:

```
location /static {
    alias /root/se/env/public/static;
}
```

or:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /root/se/env/public/static/;
}
```

In fact, because the `alias` parameter ends with the `location` parameter, you should not be using the `alias` directive at all. See the note at the end of [the `alias` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

```
location /static {
    root /root/se/env/public;
}
```

Comment: good catch, thanks. I haven't managed to get the admin css to show for prod yet but this got me one step closer.